# Search bar for dynamic list view

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to view all objects from the database in one table. When you click on a record, on the side you can see details about it.

I would like to also do a searchbar, that will help with finding the desired record in the list. I can't find a working solution. I would like not to lose the dynamic list design. Every solution uses a static resource list.

---

My code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="list row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item"
                    :class="{ active: index == currentIndex }"
                    v-for="(client, index) in clients"
                    :key="index"
                    @click="setActiveClient(client, index)"
                >
                    {{ client.name + ' ' + client.surname}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div v-if="currentClient">
                <h4>Klient</h4>
                <div>
                    <label><strong>Imię:</strong></label> {{ currentClient.name }}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label><strong>Nazwisko:</strong></label> {{ currentClient.surname }}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label><strong>Nr Telefonu:</strong></label> {{ currentClient.phoneNumber }}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label><strong>Email:</strong></label> {{ currentClient.email }}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label><strong>Notatka:</strong></label> {{ currentClient.description }}
                </div>

                <a class="badge badge-warning"
                   :href="'/clients/' + currentClient.id"
                >
                    Edytuj
                </a>
            </div>
            <a href="/addClient" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Dodaj</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add computed property that would return the list after being matched. I recently used this approach in my project. It turns out to be efficient and easy.

**data**

```
data() {
  return {
     clients: [], // will contain your data
     searchKey: ""
}
```

**search input box in the template**

```
<input placeholder='enter search key' v-model="searchKey" />
```

**computed property**

```
computed: {
  getClients() {
   let r = new RegExp(this.searchKey, 'i'); // will search irrespective of casing

   return !!this.searchKey ? this.clients.filter( v => 
        r.test(v.name) ||
        r.test(v.surname) // add more search options if you want
    )  : this.clients;

  }
}
```

Now in your list replace `clients` with `getClients`

```
<li class="list-group-item"
                    :class="{ active: index == currentIndex }"
                    v-for="(client, index) in getClients" // here
                    :key="index"
                    @click="setActiveClient(client, index)"
                >
                    {{ client.name + ' ' + client.surname}}
                </li>
```

If your searchKey is empty, which means user has not entered any search predicate, it will show all the clients, otherwise it will show only one that match `name` **or** `surname`

Comment: Working great! But when you have your computed method, there is double negation in return instruction. You just have to remove "!!" at begginig.

Comment: Yes, ik linter issues :D